# SailsJS how to specify file paths at the root level of project

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I got a SailsJS application in which I need to reference a htpasswd file that is located at the root of my project:

```
var auth = require('http-auth');

var basic = auth.basic({
    authRealm: "Admin Panel",
    authFile: 'htpasswd', // <-- how do I specify the path to this file ?
    authType: 'basic'
});

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    basic.apply(req, res, function(username) {
        if(!username) {
            return res.serverError(403, 'You are not authorized');
        }

        next();
    })(req, res);
}
```

I have tried using:

```
authFile: '/htpasswd'
```

As well as:

```
authFile: '~/htpasswd'
```

Neither works.

### Update

Hurmm....it seems like it's not the code that has error, somehow, my Sailsjs application can't find the htpasswd module.

I did do:

```
sudo npm install -g htpasswd
```

I also used htpasswd command line to generate the `htpasswd` file...somethings wrong with my project setup...

My console error says:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'htpasswd'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MacUser/SailsProjects/SecurePanel/node_modules/http-auth/gensrc/auth/basic.js:11:14)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the native `__dirname` variable which evaluates to the path of the current file.

See what it is using `console.log(__dirname)`. And then you could do:

```
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Admin Panel",
    file: __dirname + "/path_from_current_file_to/htpasswd"
});
```

So if the root was a folder up from this the folder that this script is in, you could do

`__dirname + "/../htpasswd"`

Comment: Is there no way to quickly jump to the root of the folder in Nodejs ? It just seems rather...odd to have to type `../../../../../.........` you know what I mean? :D

Comment: By root of the folder, do you mean the filesytem? Or the project? Because I thought you were referring to the latter?

Comment: And no, unless you store a reference to the root, Node.js has no way of figuring out what the root project folder is. You should store it in an environment variable or something, and then access  it. Better yet, a config file.

Comment: I did mean the project root instead of my Mac's filesystem. Maybe I should use Passport's basic auth instead.